# xCode 4.3 crashes on pause or breakpoint

Tags: xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access

I have an app running on xCode 4.2 without any issues.

Installed xCode 4.3, ran the application and after tweaking the project settings got it working on both.

I added a breakpoint, upon hitting the breakpoint then running again I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the top of the stack on THREAD 1 in the following code section :

```
0x28d0:  pushl  $0
0x28d2:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x28d4:  andl   $240, %esp
0x28d7:  subl   $16, %esp
0x28da:  movl   4(%ebp), %ebx
0x28dd:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x28e0:  leal   8(%ebp), %ecx
0x28e3:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x28e7:  addl   $1, %ebx
0x28ea:  shll   $2, %ebx
0x28ed:  addl   %ecx, %ebx
0x28ef:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x28f3:  movl   (%ebx), %eax <- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe364d528)
0x28f5:  addl   $4, %ebx
0x28f8:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x28fa:  jne    0x28f3                   ; start + 35
0x28fc:  movl   %ebx, 12(%esp)
0x2900:  calll  0x2910                   ; main at main.m:11
0x2905:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2908:  calll  0x26089a                 ; exit
0x290d:  hlt
```

This happens at any breakpoint, anywhere, any thread. It also happens when I pause and try to continue, it also happens when I try to step over/in any line of code.

Ideas on why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: I get this in Xcode 6-Beta1! INCREDIBLY frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

I switched the debugger from LLDB back to GDB under Schemes and it doesn't crash every time now.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905378/xcode-4-3-4-4-crashes-with-breakpoints-using-lldb-breakpoints-useless-with-gdb/11961253?iemail=1#11961253) might solve your problem.  It sounds similar to my issue, except that for me Xcode as a whole was crashing, not just the app.  The fix outlined in that question worked for me.