# Xcode 4.3-4.4 crashes with breakpoints using LLDB, breakpoints useless with GDB

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, breakpoints, lldb

Every time I try to run my target when Breakpoints using the LLDB Debugger, Xcode crashes.
My colleague has no trouble using LLDB, and we're both running 4.4 (I've had the problem since 4.3)

Furthermore, since I have to use GDB, there's a problem with that too.  Randomly, when I hit some breakpoints in GDB, I'll get a `Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)` message, and can't really see anything useful without blindly typing in `po iVar` like commands.

Overall my debugging is pretty busted, if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

NOTE: My project is compiling with Apple LLVM 3.0 and cannot revert back without causing build errors due to the use of the `-fobjc-arc` compiler flag

Here's the crash report from Xcode

```
Process:         Xcode [344]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.4 (1484)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1484000000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 9584584
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [324]

Date/Time:       2012-08-10 11:45:01.067 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          83007 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  80976 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      50D9F896-324C-4624-8C00-C460577BD2AE

Crashed Thread:  16  <lldb session listener>

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010bacd000-000000010bad0000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4F250
objc[344]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d367a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d2d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687950c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b8a34d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b8aa781 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b8aa60e BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d614e31 _DPSNextEvent + 659
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d614735 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d611071 -[NSApplication run] + 470
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d88d244 NSApplicationMain + 867
12  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010bacedc0 0x10bacd000 + 7616

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d57e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e2aa78a _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e2a931a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d367a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d2d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687950c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff82510fd7 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 335
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8250572a -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff825056a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d367a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d2d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687950c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x00000001118c9eaf -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 298
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8250572a -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff825056a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4df2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff868cac8b __CFSocketManager + 1355
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d367a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d2d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687950c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff824b6f7b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff824b6e67 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 62
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8250572a -[NSThread main] + 68
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff825056a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6f274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010f3b3d35 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 353
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8250572a -[NSThread main] + 68
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff825056a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6f274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8e7906c8 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 710
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8e7903e9 _ZL13startIOThreadPv + 148
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d5192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6d594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4e42 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a2197e pthread_join + 795
2   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d41c4ea 0x10cedf000 + 5493994
3   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d41201a 0x10cedf000 + 5451802
4   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cee93f7 0x10cedf000 + 41975
5   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cf1f913 clang_indexSourceFile + 163
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010c3152ff -[IDEIndexClangTranslationUnit indexUsingDataSource:] + 295
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010c3146b2 -[IDEIndexClangDataSource generateDataForJob:] + 2182
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010c313db7 -[IDEIndexDataSource processJob:] + 243
9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010c3139e9 +[IDEIndexingEngine runFileJob:] + 414
10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010c31345e -[IDEIndexingJob run] + 99
11  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010c43434d __40-[IDEIndexingJobScheduler _scheduleJobs]_block_invoke_0 + 31
12  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bb7c260 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke_0 + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e2a8a86 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e2a9965 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 255
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6d3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d5192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6d594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d5192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6d594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:: <lldb.comm.debugger.input>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4df2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3e5d6 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 362
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3e151 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 141
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3c9ac lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 50
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3c653 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 225
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121dafb38 _ZL22ThreadCreateTrampolinePv + 91
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: <lldb.comm.xcode.lldb.comm>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4df2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3e5d6 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 362
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3e151 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 141
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3c9ac lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 50
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d3c653 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 225
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121dafb38 _ZL22ThreadCreateTrampolinePv + 91
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: <lldb.process.gdb-remote.async>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6f274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121daf3d5 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d51ce0 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 100
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d52a46 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 156
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d52bed lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121df3457 ProcessGDBRemote::AsyncThread(void*) + 277
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121dafb38 _ZL22ThreadCreateTrampolinePv + 91
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=6712)>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6f274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121daf3d5 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d51ce0 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 100
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d52a46 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 156
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d52bed lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e54e1a lldb_private::Process::WaitForEventsPrivate(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&, bool) + 148
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e59d3f lldb_private::Process::RunPrivateStateThread() + 149
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e59a09 lldb_private::Process::PrivateStateThread(void*) + 9
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121dafb38 _ZL22ThreadCreateTrampolinePv + 91
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 16 Crashed:: <lldb session listener>
0   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6fabb3 d_type + 1274
1   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6fae48 d_type + 1935
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6fadf2 d_type + 1849
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6fec48 d_bare_function_type + 119
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6feb29 d_encoding + 1599
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6fa57c d_demangle + 498
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b6fa305 __cxa_demangle + 81
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d546ef lldb_private::Mangled::GetDemangledName() const + 127
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e43251 lldb_private::Symtab::InitNameIndexes() + 209
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e4398f lldb_private::Symtab::AppendSymbolIndexesWithName(lldb_private::ConstString const&, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&) + 103
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121de20e1 ObjectFileMachO::ParseSymtab(bool) + 10381
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121ddf7d0 ObjectFileMachO::GetSymtab() + 132
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d55f3f lldb_private::Module::ResolveSymbolContextForAddress(lldb_private::Address const&, unsigned int, lldb_private::SymbolContext&) + 273
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d37f2c lldb_private::Address::CalculateSymbolContext(lldb_private::SymbolContext*, unsigned int) const + 158
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e365e5 lldb_private::CompileUnit::ResolveSymbolContext(lldb_private::FileSpec const&, unsigned int, bool, bool, unsigned int, lldb_private::SymbolContextList&) + 733
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d0098e lldb_private::BreakpointResolverFileLine::SearchCallback(lldb_private::SearchFilter&, lldb_private::SymbolContext&, lldb_private::Address*, bool) + 384
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d665fc lldb_private::SearchFilter::DoModuleIteration(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, lldb_private::Searcher&) + 346
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121d6646d lldb_private::SearchFilter::Search(lldb_private::Searcher&) + 127
18  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e69396 lldb_private::Target::CreateBreakpoint(std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::SearchFilter>&, std::tr1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::BreakpointResolver>&, bool) + 318
19  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121e694b5 lldb_private::Target::CreateBreakpoint(lldb_private::FileSpecList const*, lldb_private::FileSpec const&, unsigned int, bool, lldb_private::LazyBool, bool) + 147
20  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000120f8be95 lldb::SBTarget::BreakpointCreateByLocation(lldb::SBFileSpec const&, unsigned int) + 203
21  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000120f8bd98 lldb::SBTarget::BreakpointCreateByLocation(char const*, unsigned int) + 58
22  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x000000010fbad1d9 -[DBGLLDBSession _createBreakpointFromFileBreakpoint:] + 150
23  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x000000010fbacd9d -[DBGLLDBSession createBreakpoint:] + 243
24  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerFoundation 0x000000010f9e245a -[DBGDebugSession _createBreakpointIfNeccessary:] + 77
25  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerFoundation 0x000000010f9e2a61 -[DBGDebugSession _handleBreakpointActivationChanged] + 191
26  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x000000010fba9ed2 _ZL20DBGLLDBSessionThreadPv + 1753
27  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000121dafb38 _ZL22ThreadCreateTrampolinePv + 91
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
29  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d367a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d2d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8687950c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86881486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff873342f2 _ZL20SpotlightQueryThreadPv + 434
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2d4ad2 __open + 10
1   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d3d6614 0x10cedf000 + 5207572
2   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d3d4d10 0x10cedf000 + 5201168
3   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d3d4e9d 0x10cedf000 + 5201565
4   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cfb3dec 0x10cedf000 + 871916
5   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cfba3e4 0x10cedf000 + 898020
6   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cfb983c 0x10cedf000 + 895036
7   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cfbacb9 0x10cedf000 + 900281
8   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cf3b357 0x10cedf000 + 377687
9   libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cf3b234 0x10cedf000 + 377396
10  libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cf530d9 0x10cedf000 + 475353
11  libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cf319b4 0x10cedf000 + 338356
12  libclang.dylib                  0x000000010cf2048f 0x10cedf000 + 267407
13  libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d411f9e 0x10cedf000 + 5451678
14  libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d412049 0x10cedf000 + 5451849
15  libclang.dylib                  0x000000010d41c50d 0x10cedf000 + 5494029
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6b8bf _pthread_start + 335
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff83a6eb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 16 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000128cf0608  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x00007fff8b6fac79
  rdi: 0x0000000128cf0608  rsi: 0x00007fff72ec4560  rbp: 0x0000000128cefab0  rsp: 0x0000000128cefa80
   r8: 0x00007fff72ec46e8   r9: 0x00007fff72ec46e8  r10: 0x000000012cd567f1  r11: 0x0000000000000052
  r12: 0x0000000128cefdf8  r13: 0x0000000128cf0770  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000128cefa88
  rip: 0x00007fff8b6fabb3  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x000000010d4f92d0
Logical CPU: 0

Model: Macmini4,1, BootROM MM41.0042.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.65f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.4.20)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.5f11, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0x24100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0x24120000 / 3
USB Device: iPhone, apple_vendor_id, 0x12a0, 0x26200000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06600000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0x06630000 / 5
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x06500000 / 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently fixed some name demangling issues. The name demangler is built into the OS in libc++abi.dylib. You can build this yourself and install it to possibly fix your issues:

```
% sudo cp /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib.orig
% svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/trunk libcxxabi
% cd libcxxabi/lib
% TRIPLE=x86_64-apple-macosx ./buildit
% sudo cp libc++abi.dylib /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
```

You can also just "try it out" without installing the "libc++abi.dylib" to make sure it fixes things first. The steps for that are:

Quit Xcode first, and then:

```
% svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/trunk libcxxabi
% cd libcxxabi/lib
% TRIPLE=x86_64-apple-macosx ./buildit
% DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

This will run Xcode and allow it to use the local copy of "libc++abi.dylib" that you just built.

Comment: Though this seemed to solve the LLDB problem just fine, it seems to have caused an issue with [__SourceTree__](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which now crashes on startup whenever I use the patched version of `libc++abi.dylib`

Comment: Please install Xcode 4.5; the workaround Greg posted isn't necessary any longer.