# Xcode crash on trying to Edit Breakpoint

Tags: xcode, crash, breakpoints, lldb

So I've gotten LLDB working in Xcode with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905378/xcode-4-3-4-4-crashes-with-breakpoints-using-lldb-breakpoints-useless-with-gdb). Now however whenever I try to edit a breakpoint within Xcode, I get a crash. You can see from the backtrace of the crashed thread, frame 7 and 8 points towards the libc++abi.dylib possibly being involved. Manipulating breakpoint objects form the console of LLDB seems to work just fine

Here's the crash log:

```
Process:         Xcode [21079]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.4.1 (1488)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1488000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 9950605
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [295]

Date/Time:       2012-08-16 17:02:42.589 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          37967 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           43
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  98301 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      50D9F896-324C-4624-8C00-C460577BD2AE

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000001280

VM Regions Near 0x1280:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010d4df000-000000010d4e2000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4F1003
objc[21079]: garbage collection is ON
Performing @selector(_editBreakpoint:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x40430d3c0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff933cd75f realizeClass(class_t*) + 197
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff933d349e prepareForMethodLookup + 116
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff933d32bb lookUpMethod + 63
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff933d5a5c class_respondsToSelector + 26
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b4cf002 objectIsKindOfClass + 66
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b4cf062 __exceptionMatch + 18
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff933ddb36 _objc_exception_do_catch + 125
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010e90ff55 scan_eh_tab + 1333
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010e90f8d8 __gxx_personality_v0 + 104
9   libunwind.dylib                 0x00007fff8e20091f _Unwind_RaiseException + 139
10  libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000010e90ebb8 __cxa_throw + 104
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff933dde7a objc_exception_throw + 327
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b4ced8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b4ced14 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff929f043b LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE + 101
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff929e0d4a -[NSISEngine handleUnsatisfiableRowWithHead:body:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 427
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff929defbe -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:constraintName:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 397
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff929e2bf1 -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 484
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff929e79d8 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 443
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9230d678 -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngineDidChange] + 296
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92308530 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 1301
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92236ac8 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b45ccb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92308a3e -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92236ac8 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b45ccb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92308a3e -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92236ac8 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b45ccb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92308a3e -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2595
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92306c6d -[NSView addSubview:] + 405
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92375270 -[NSWindow setContentView:] + 376
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92a4bcfc -[_NSPopoverWindow setContentView:] + 69
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92a40874 -[NSPopover _makePopoverWindowIfNeeded] + 519
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92a400fa -[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:] + 1031
35  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerUI     0x0000000110d1c562 +[IDEBreakpointEditorPopoverViewController showEditorForBreakpoint:relativeToRect:ofView:] + 193
36  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerUI     0x0000000110d109ee -[DBGBreakpointAnnotationProvider _editBreakpointForAnnotation:inTextSideBarView:] + 213
37  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b4be70d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff922f9f7e -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
39  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010d9190b8 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 318
40  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e113219 -[IDEApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 154
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff923e6bfb -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 399
42  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff923e6932 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 125
43  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92685dd4 -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 38
44  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92514a91 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 138
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92360e0b NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 339
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9048b448 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1263
47  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9048aa54 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 446
48  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff904a18f3 SendEventToEventTarget + 76
49  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff904e799d SendHICommandEvent(unsigned int, HICommand const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) + 398
50  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff905cf035 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 56
51  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff906167a9 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 253
52  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff904e0a6b FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) + 101
53  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9060f1e1 PopUpMenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, Point, unsigned short, unsigned int, Rect const*, unsigned short, unsigned int, Rect const*, Rect const*, __CFString const*, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 1660
54  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9060f4a0 _HandlePopUpMenuSelection7 + 621
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9251775d _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 3860
56  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9251575d -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:withFont:] + 190
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92685c0b -[NSMenu _popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:withFont:] + 193
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9286d086 -[NSView rightMouseDown:] + 129
59  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9271f32a -[NSRulerView rightMouseDown:] + 561
60  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff922c37ac -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 7430
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9225ca55 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
62  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e10f2b4 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 369
63  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff921f30c6 -[NSApplication run] + 555
64  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9246f244 NSApplicationMain + 867
65  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010d4e0dc0 0x10d4df000 + 7616

Model: Macmini4,1, BootROM MM41.0042.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.65f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.4.20)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.5f11, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0x24100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0x24120000 / 3
USB Device: iPhone, apple_vendor_id, 0x12a0, 0x26400000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06600000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0x06630000 / 5
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x06500000 / 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running Xcode 4.4 -- if at all possible, please update to Xcode 4.5.  The C++ demangling fix was included in Xcode 4.5 and the workaround previously posted is not needed any longer (and may very well cause problems like the one you're having.)

Comment: I can confirm that Xcode 4.5 has fixed these problems and my development environment is back to normal, thank you!